# Scrolling buttons to link Div Id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a template where i want to link top and down buttons to div id's. I searched alot how to do it but can't find any tutorial. Please click on below link you will see 2 buttons on left side i want when somebody click on Up or down button it should scroll accordingly.

http://yasirjamal.co.cc/Page-Scrolling/

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

View this may be help you.

http://blog.freelancer-id.com/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery/

Comment: Thanks Harry, :)

But the problem is its not easing. I need it on same effect the one i posted.